# Separating class for $C[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

The finite dimensional sets $\mathcal{C}:=\{\pi_{t_1,\ldots, t_d}^{-1}(B) : {t_1,\ldots, t_d} \in [0,1]$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)\}$ forms a separating class for $C[0,1]$. This is proved by showing that $\mathcal{C}$ forms a $\pi$-system and that they generate the Borel $\sigma-$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,1]}$. I was wondering if the system $\mathcal{C}_0:=\{\pi_{t}^{-1}(B) : t\in [0,1]$ and $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ is also a determining class since it also generate $\sigma-$-algebra $\mathcal{B}_{C[0,1]}$. Since I cannot find it i'd excpect that this is not true. Isn't $\mathcal{C}_0$ a $\pi$-system either?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal C_0$ is not a $\pi$ system. For example $\{f\in C[0,1]: f(0)>0\} \cap \{f\in C[0,1]: f(1)>0\}$ cannot be written as $\{f\in C[0,1]: f(t) \in B \}$ for any Borel set $B$. ( You can always find a continuous function f such that $f(0)=f(1)=1$ but $f(t) \notin B$ since $B$ cannot be $\mathbb R$).

Comment: Thank you. $\mathcal{C}$ obviously contains $C_0$ and therefore your sets are also elements in $\mathcal{C}$. Can you explain how the intersection of your example could be written as a set in $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: $\{f\in C[0,1]: f(0)>0\} \cap \{f\in C[0,1]: f(1)>0\}=\pi_{0,1}^{-1}(B)$ where $B=(0,\infty) \times (0,\infty)$.

Comment: Thanks. Just to be sure: The same example holds if I look at the space $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ instead of $C[0,1]$, right?

Comment: Right. In fact what you were trying to show is that a probability distribution on $C[0,1]$ or $\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ is completely determined by its marginals. This is false, of course.

Comment: Now I am trying to move to the "next" level, trying to find a separating class for the cadlag space $D[0,1]$. The finite dim. sets $\mathcal{D}$ are again a $\pi$-system. But (I think) that $\sigma(\mathcal{D})\neq\mathcal{B}_{(D[0,1],\rho)}$, so they don't generate the Borel $\sigma$-field if $D[0,1]$ is equipped with the uniform metric $\rho$. Can someone prove that? If $D[0,1]$ is instead equipped with the Skorohod metric $d_S$, I think that we have $\sigma(\mathcal{D})=\mathcal{B}_{(D[0,1], d_S)}$? I cannot find some literature (except Billingsley which is very hard to read) on that.